# How to extract text from xml error message python

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I want to determine if the return from a beautifulsoup request looks like this.

```
Out[32]: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<boardgames termsofuse="https://boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi/termsofuse">
<boardgame>
<error message="Item not found"/>
</boardgame>
</boardgames>
```

I can extract the center of the previous output using:

```
soup.find_all('boardgame')[0], which produces the following:

Out[24]: 
<boardgame>
<error message="Item not found"/>
</boardgame>
```

I feel like this should be so easy, and I've tried the following, but I still can't determine if the "error message="Item not found" is in there.  What am I missing here?

```
soup.findAll('boardgame')[0].getText()
Out[26]: '\n\n'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the attribute `message` to get the value.If you to find the `error` tag first and then use the attribute `message`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data='''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<boardgames termsofuse="https://boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi/termsofuse">
<boardgame>
<error message="Item not found"/>
</boardgame>
</boardgames>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
message=soup.find('boardgame').find('error')['message']
print(message)
```

Output:

> Item not found

---

Or you can use css selector

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data='''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<boardgames termsofuse="https://boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi/termsofuse">
<boardgame>
<error message="Item not found"/>
</boardgame>
</boardgames>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')

message=soup.select_one('boardgame error')['message']
print(message)
```

Output:

> Item not found